# Prove that $\;X^{Y^Z} ≠ \left(X^Y\right)^Z\;$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I transformed it to:[image: pic]
$$Y^Z ≠ Z*Y$$ 
Do I need to go any further? And if yes, how?

Comment: Well, no one can tell if you need to go further. Do you know that $Y^Z= ZY$ is not always true (might be true, for some rare instances of $Y$ and $Z$, though)? How would you convince others of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that a statement is not true, you need to provide just one instance where it fails.

For example,let $x=2,y=1,z=3$.
Then $x^{(y^z)}=2$ and $(x^y)^{z}=8$.

Comment: Isnt it going with a shortcut? I know that it proves it, but I think thats not the way this should be handled. You can't do the same on harder examples and its just a practice.

Comment: Perhaps then, as G.Sassatelli suggests in the comments, you can do the calculation you did and now try to find $y,z$ such that $yz\neq y^z$. This is much easier right?